# Where should Global.asax reside on an ASP.NET MVC 4 solution with multiple projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

If for example I have a solution with two projects: Project.Core and Project.Web. Now I set Project.Web as the startup project. Shall global.asax reside on the root of this project (Project.Web)? If so, do I also have to include the App_Start folder on my Project.Web because this folder has the classes being called in global.asax (like routing, filter, bundling, auth, and etc.)?

If on the contrary, I put global.asax on Project.Core (not the startup project)... will it still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global.asax file is there to help with web related events(Application_Start, Application_BeginRequest, etc) so putting it in Project.Core defeats the purpose of creating two projects.

Comment: Thanks. I had a misinformed impression before that global.asax.cs could be located on any project within the solution... and that this gets run first irregardless if the project where it resides is the startup project or not.